# How to get the first 100 unique places in df in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df1 like:

```
     Date        Area               Fips score1   
    2020-01-21 Snohomish,Washington 53061 1
    2020-01-22 Snohomish,Washington 53061 1
    2020-01-23 Snohomish,Washington 53061 1
    2020-01-24 Cook,Illinois        17031 1
    2020-01-24 Snohomish,Washington 53061 1
    2020-01-25 Orange,California    06059 1
    2020-01-25 Cook,Illinois        17031 1
    2020-01-25 Snohomish,Washington 53061 1
    2020-01-26 Maricopa,Arizona     04013 1
    2020-01-26 Los Angeles,California 06037 1
```

I would like to make a dataframe of the first 100 unique counties ordered by date, output:

```
 Date        Area               Fips score1   
2020-01-21 Snohomish,Washington 53061 1
2020-01-24 Cook,Illinois        17031 1
2020-01-25 Orange,California    06059 1
2020-01-26 Maricopa,Arizona     04013 1
2020-01-26 Los Angeles,California 06037 1
```

Comment: Does `unique` work for you?

Comment: I just want the first 100?

Comment: You can `slice` or use any `subset` alternative I guess.

Comment: I'm not proficient enough in R to know the exact syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
    distinct(Area, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
    head(100) %>%
    arrange(Date)
```

Comment: i think op wants to sort by county, date first, then take the first 100 unique

Comment: Counties are not sorted alphabetically in the expected outcome though. If @rawr is right, then `df1 %>% arrange(Area, Date) %>% distinct(Area, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% head(100)`

Comment: yeah I think you're right about area, so maybe `df > arrange(Date) > ...`, i'm not totally sure

Comment: it's a possibility, yea

Answer (score 3):

In *base* you can use `order` to order by *Date*, `!duplicated` to get *unique* Area and `head` to get the first 100 like:

```
i <- order(df1$Date)
head(df1[i,][!duplicated(df1$Area[i]),], 100)
#         Date                   Area  Fips score1
#1  2020-01-21   Snohomish,Washington 53061      1
#4  2020-01-24          Cook,Illinois 17031      1
#6  2020-01-25      Orange,California  6059      1
#9  2020-01-26       Maricopa,Arizona  4013      1
#10 2020-01-26 Los_Angeles,California  6037      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df1)[order(Date)], by = 'Area')[seq_len(100)]
```